# Imitating the Arc System Works anime topology but I'm getting shading problems

Tags: topology

I want my model to have expressive mouths. I see other people's models have triangle faces around the mouth which allow them to have extreme expressive look like in anime. This is from the game dev studio Arc System Works. When I do that the faces look wrinkly. What am I doing wrong?

This is my character.
[image: Mark]
[image: Mark Wireframe]

These are the examples I'm trying to follow

[image: Character from Gulty Gear]

[image: rukikuri]

Thanks in advance!